# I want to call debugger on each field value change with spring aop

Tags: spring-aop

I want to call debug automatically when any field(parameter) value changes in application with spring aop. is this possible? (If yes please give me solution)

THANKS in advance

Comment: What do you mean _call debug_? Spring AOP is only implemented at the method invocation join point level. You cannot detect field value changes directly.

Comment: Thanks for reply Sotirios Delimanolis,                             but Actually I am trying to move all logger debug, info and error statement from all java classes to Aspectj class in a advice
log.info at method start & end  and log .error for exception is succefully moved with advices before, after and throwing advices.
debug statment with method return value is also mapped with returning advice
but struggling in other debug statements
e.g. 
log.deug(" i = " + i);
i = i+2;
log.deug(" i = " + i);
I am not able to move this in AspectJ